# How to pass an index into setTimeout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this on here, but none that I've seen answer this for me.  If I missed one, and this is a duplicate, sorry.

I'm trying to modify my graph using d3 and want to use setTimeout to space the operations in a nice looking way.

I have

```
for (var key in alist){
    setTimeout(function () {
        graph.removeLink(alist[key].source.name, alist[key].target.name);
    }(key), key*500+200);
}
```

This calls the removeLink function immediately instead of waiting the set interval.

I'm new to javascript, so sorry if this is something exceptionally obvious, I can't find an answer anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind the variable to the anonymous function on the fly, or create a function to wrap the timeout in.

Anonymous function bind:

```
for (var key in alist){
    setTimeout(function (alistitem) {
        graph.removeLink(alistitem.source.name, alistitem.target.name);
    }.bind(this, alist[key]), key*500+200);
}
```

Separate function:

```
function timedRemoveLink(item, time){
   setTimeout(function() {
     graph.removeLink(item.source.name, item.target.name);
   }, time);
};

for (var key in alist){
    timedRemoveLink(alist[key], key*500+200);
}
```

Comment: thanks, is there a common convention for javascript in regard to this.  ie. Is it better to bind variables like that or to use a separate function?

Comment: @Damien I'm not sure on what is considered 'proper' (I'm sure you'll hear many, often contrary, opinions.) but I always prefer clarity over cleverness. The separate function is cleaner in my opinion, and easier to debug.

That being said you should really look into `.bind` because it can be extremely useful in many situations.

Answer (score 0):

You called your anonymous function when you tried to pass the key in.  Instead, use a closure.  Make sure to make a local copy of the key!

```
for (var key in alist){
    var keyCopy = key;

    setTimeout(function () {
        graph.removeLink(alist[keyCopy].source.name, alist[keyCopy].target.name);
    }, key*500+200);
}
```